# can't access the database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm building an android application which gets the cellID,mcc,mnc and lac of the tower my phone is connected to.I then want to query a MySQL database, which is on my localhost,by sending the value got from the android application in the WHERE clause in the db query.However when i try to do so through my php script it gives an error..here's a snippet of the code:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM gsm_info WHERE mcc='".$_REQUEST['mcc']."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' >";
echo "<tr> <th>lat</th> <th>lon</th> <th>mcc</th> <th>mnc</th> <th>lac</th> <th>cellid</th> </tr>"; 
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $rows['lat'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $rows['lon'];
```

when i open the browser to run the php file,sfter running the app on my android emulator,it gives an error saying 'undefined index mcc'...hope to get some help

Comment: What error it gives when you run it via php? maybe that MCC really doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump( $_REQUEST );` to see if `mcc` is actually being passed.

Answer (score 0):

From description of your error it seems that you are not properly setting your 'mcc' parameter in Android code. Check Android code that invokes request or if you are not sure, post it here so that we can see what can be the problem.